# Apache Kafka VirtualBox: Streaming data from VM to Host PC resulting in error connecting to node

Tags: java, apache-kafka, virtualbox

I recently started using Apache Kafka and was successful sending data from producer to consumer within Windows 10 and my Linux Mint 19.3 (VM) environments. Now I want to stream data from my VM to my Windows 10 environment.

Both environments are able to ping each other.

When I try to run my consumer on Windows 10, I get an "Error connecting to node VM-VirtualBox:9092'" followed by a "java.net.UnknownHostException: VM-VirtualBox". Strangely, Windows 10 is able to SEE the topics listed on the VM environment; and I am able to create and delete topics from Windows. But I just cannot connect.

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

My server.properties include lines:

```html
broker.id=0
Kafka Broker Advanced Configuration
Snippet (Safety Valve)
############################# Socket Server Settings #############################
# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
# FORMAT:
# listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
# EXAMPLE:
# listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#port=9092
#advertised.host.name=localhost
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://VM-VirtualBox:9092
#advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://Windows10-7950:9092
domain:9092
```

I've also posted this on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/apachekafka/comments/emqbms/virtualbox_streaming_data_from_vm_to_host_pc/

Comment: Also, on the VM side, I have the Zookeeper and Kafka servers running. And a producer Python application that sends random characters to the topic. I've tested out the program within Linux Mint and data is able to stream to the consumer terminal.

Comment: I would like to add that if I un-comment "advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://Widows10-7950:9092" and then run the kafka-console-consumer.bat command on Windows 10, I get this error:

Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {Coordinates=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

I feel like streaming data from VM to host PC should be a simple procedure, But I have been stuck on this for 2 days. Please, If anyone could point out what I am doing wrong, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Kafka is running on the host, you need to advertise the hosts hostname, or some address that the VM can resolve (it can be an IP address, too)

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://EXTERNAL-HOST:9092
```

Otherwise, you need to edit the hosts file in the OS such that the DNS name is recognized

The reason you can list and create topics is because you're probably using Zookeeper, not the bootstrap address

Comment: Just want to clarify, on the VM side, its server.properties has the line "advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://VM-VirtualBox:9092". On the Windows 10 side, should I add the same line to its  server.properties file, but change the host-name to the VM-VirtualBox? Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Thank you! It was a port forwarding issue. I'm using a bridged connection on my VM. With VM active I went into File->Preferences and Network. Added a new NAT. In port forwarding rules I put my Windows IP address as Host IP and VM as Guest IP and created two entries for ports 2181 and 9092.
 
In the VM's server.propertie file, I modified to rules and simplyadded
listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners = PLAINTEXT://Windows10-7950:9092

Now everything works! Thanks!

Comment: The VM needs to advertise its external IP... **if you forward the port**, you would only need to advertise `localhost`. If you are not running a Kafka broker on windows, then don't touch its properties file. https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/